# Calculate volume of a cone using its angle

Tags: geometry

I'm supposed to compute a way to calculate the volume of a cone using its angle at the top (which is given), using the next formula:

$V=\iiint\rho^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\rho d\theta d\phi$

With:

- $0<\rho<R$, $R$ being the radius of the base of the cone
- $0<\theta<\pi/4$ which is the variable corresponding to the angle at the top of the cone (the angle being $\pi/2$)
- $0<\phi<2\pi$

By both using sympy and calculating by hand, I get $V=\dfrac{\pi R^3}{6}$

I know it's not really complicated, but I've looked on internet for a bit but I couldn't find anything about calculating the volume of a cone that way, and couldn't verify if my result is correct. I guess it is, but I'm now curious why there's so little information on the internet. I guess it might not be the most efficient way to do it, but any why barely nobody speaks about that method ?

Comment: You can see the Gauss theorem,Stokes Theorem and Green's theorem which is related to divergence theorem.It can be solved easily.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is then,
$V=\iiint_{V}dV=$$\iiint_V \rho^2 cos \theta sin\theta \,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi$$ $
$=$$\int_{\rho=0}^{R} \rho^2\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} cos \theta sin\theta \,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi$$ $
$=$$\int_{\rho=0}^{R} \rho^2 \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos \theta sin\theta \,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi$$ $
$=$$\int_{\rho=0}^{R} \rho^2 d\rho \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos \theta sin\theta \,d\theta$$ $

$=$$[\frac{\rho^3}{3}]_{\rho=0}^{R} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos \theta sin\theta \,d\theta$$ $
$=$$\frac{R^3}{3}[\phi]_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos \theta sin\theta \,d\theta$$ $
$=$$\frac{R^3}{3}2\pi\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}2 cos \theta sin\theta \,d\theta$$ $
$=$$\frac{R^3}{3}2\pi\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} sin2\theta \,d\theta$$ $
$=$$\frac{R^3}{3}2\pi\frac{1}{2}[\frac{-cos2\theta}{2}]_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$ $

$=$$\frac{R^3}{3}2\pi\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}[0-(-1)]$$ $
$=\frac{\pi R^3}{2.3}$
$=\frac{\pi R^3}{6}$

*You can draw a cone and mention its respective angel as directed then it will be cleared.When we will get individual constant limit of the each  integral then it is easy otherwise need to transfer others formula(Stoke's,Green's if Possible) or change the integral their places.